# Using System.Reflection and resources in Phalanger

Tags: phalanger

I need to embed some resource in a pure compiled dll written in php using phalanger.
These are txt files tha I set in visual studio as "Embedded Resource".

My problem is that I cannot use the Assembly class to get the resource using GetManifestResourceStream.

I tried code like this:
    use System\Reflection\Assembly

```
$asm = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly(); //this gives me mscorlib instead of my dll
$str = $asm->GetManifestResourceStream("name");
```

My question is: how do I get access to embedded resources in phalanger?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, why Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly() returns an incorrect value. Anyway to workaround the $asm value, use following code:

```
$MyType = CLRTypeOf MyProgram;
$asm = $MyType->Assembly;
```

Then you can access embedded resources as you posted

```
$asm->GetManifestResourceStream("TextFile1.txt");
```

or you can include standard resource file (.resx) into your project, and use \System\Resources\ResourceManager

```
$this->manager = new \System\Resources\ResourceManager("",$asm);
$this->manager->GetObject("String1",null);
```

*Just note, currently there can be just one .resx within Phalanger project*

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first solution worked great! Unfortunately if I use a streamreader to read the text file to a string (using ReadToEnd()) I get a lot of unknown bytes before getting the real file content, there is also some text that says "System.Resources.ResourceReader...". I wrote the same code in c# ad got only the file ccontent as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but the part of the Phalanger code (`Php.Core.Emit.AddResourceFile()` method) responsible for this hasn't changed since this was asked. I faced the same problem and solved it in (almost) non-hacky way. You have to provide alternative name (`/res:/path/to/filename,alternative-name`) for this to work though.

```php
$asm = clr_typeof('self')->Assembly;
$resourceStream = $asm->GetManifestResourceStream("filename");
$reader = new \System\Resources\ResourceReader($resourceStream);

$type = $data = null;
$reader->GetResourceData("alternative-name", $type, $data);

// and still there are 4 excess bytes
// representing the length of the resource
$data = \substr($data, 4);
$stream  = new IO\MemoryStream($data);

// after this $stream is usable as you would expect
```

Straightforward `GetManifestResourceStream()` (as suggested by Jakub) does not work because Phalanger does not use `System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.DefineManifestResource()` (like I think it should when supplied with unrecognized file format). It uses `ModuleBuilder.DefineResource()` which returns `ResourceWriter` instead, that only really suited for `.resources` files. And this is what dictates the requirement to use `ResourceReader` when you need to read your resource.

**Note**: This answer applies to [Phalanger master branch at the time of writing](https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger/tree/e13ea87f1a635c577a409d48276f31b097a670a6) and prior versions since circa 2011. Noted because it looks like a bug (especially the need to use both original and alternative names).